# Magento2: Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: error, magento2

In Magento 1 when there is a 503 error,[`.maintenance.flag`] file gets created in root Magento directory and deleting it brings the website back to its normal stage.

In Magento 2 when there is a 503 error, [`.maintenance.flag`] is neither present in root nor in var. Where it's present?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magento 2 maintenance mode file has the name [`.maintenance.flag`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/22629abe10f9c640fe47b6081d57fedccdea8e0f/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/MaintenanceMode.php#L22) (with the leading dot) and is located in the [`var`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/22629abe10f9c640fe47b6081d57fedccdea8e0f/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/MaintenanceMode.php#L32) folder.
But HTTP `503` code response can have different causes. For example, the cause could be a webserver misconfiguration.

Answer (score 5):

- Delete the file called `.maintenance.flag` located in the **var** folder.
- If appear `Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons`, please check the error log.
- If the error log prompts **Please upgrade your database**, run:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

from the Magento root directory.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer on this page addresses the primary reason you would see a `Service Temporarily Unavailable` page.

However if you only see the error intermittently, and specifically if it's after the browser makes multiple simultaneous requests to a server that's configured to use Redis for session storage, your error may be related to [the Redis `max_concurrency` setting](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/redis/redis-session.html).

I've run into this error on a couple of Magento 2 projects and have had to increase the `max_concurrency` to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

In lots of cases, after installing a new extension and recompiling Magento 2 code, you need to set file and folder permissions again.

After running these commands through SSH:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

You then need to reset the file permissions and reset file ownership by running these commands through SSH:

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; // 644 permission for files

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; // 755 permission for directory

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; // 777 permission for var folder

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R 10000:1004 .

chmod u+x bin/magento

That should fix the "Service Temporarily Unavailable" issues.

Sometimes you might need to run this command more than once:

chown -R 10000:1004 .

Answer (score 0):

Just Disable maintenance mode as follows

bin/magento maintenance:disable

Answer (score 0):

503 (Service Unavailable) errors accessing Magento software in a web browser is shown due to the "cache problem". Here is a possible solution that works for me.
1: Login admin panel and clear cache and also cache flush
2: If you are not able to login then run this command in CLI "bin/magento cache:clean" & "bin/magento cache:flush".
3: Reindex Indexer with root dir "bin/magento indexer:reindex"

I hope it works for this error 503.

Comment: This is not true. A general concept is when you see a service related error, this is related to backend code / server config / db config and not frontend code which we can be fixed using cache clean or flash command. Also you won't be able to login if it gives 503 error.