# URGENT HELP NEEDED! in magento 2 getting list of errors after enabling developer mode through command line

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, frontend-error

i was having an error on frontend [image]

after looking for an answer here i got an answer :[Magento 2 error: We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101492/magento-2-error-were-sorry-an-error-has-occurred-while-generating-this-email)
according to which i enabled the developers mode by command line as:

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
>   and then clearing the caches:
>   php bin/magento cache:flush
>   and after refreshing the front page it gave me a crazy list of errors :

[image]

can someone guide me what to do now because my website was running but now customers have started to move on to other websites which i a great shock to me as it is a huge projct for me.

Comment: Well you should never ever enable develop mode on a production site and that too after it is live for customers. Simply now set it to production mode again.

Comment: how can i set it to production mode again?

Comment: Run this command : php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production. Keep patience while it is running because there will be some processes taking place which will take some time to finish. Good Luck!

Comment: hey i tried this and now its showing Service Temporarily Unavailable Error 503

Comment: check if this post helps - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90064/magento2-service-temporarily-unavailable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following step may be it can help you :

1. Remove all data inside directory :

   var/cache
   var/di
   var/generation
   var/view_preprocessed
   pub/static
2. check if maintenannce.flag file exist in root/var/ directory delete that file as well
3. run command bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
4. clear cache bin/magento c:f
5. check permission of file and folder (important to check)
   try to hit base url in browser.

Comment: You should really explain what these steps are doing. It was by running commands without knowing what they do that got the OP into his mess in the first place.

Comment: Actually  I am considering the person who is performing a task should have basic knowledge of magento  default command  . But If you need explanation you have following option  just run :

Comment: Actually  I am considering the person who is performing a task should have basic knowledge of magento  default command  . But If you need explanation you have following option  just run :
bin/magento  
in root folder all command are well explained .
secondly : deleting file under view processed will delete all static file magento generate for caching purpose .
deploy mode command will change mode from developer to production .
bin/magento  c:f remove all cache files .
and permission you need to check  according to  you configuration .

Comment: you can use chown and chmod command  for setting  owner and file permission

Comment: Remember that developers (and not just the OP) use Stack Exchange to learn, not just find answers to one-off questions. So explaining what the commands do is essential to help developers do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are simple steps to overcome this:

1. Empty content of root/var/cache/,  /var/page_cache/, /var/log,  /var/report ,/var/di , var/generation var/view_preprocessed
2. run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
4. run `php bin/magento cache:clean`
5. run `php bin/magento cache:flush`
6. run  4. run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`   or setup:static-content:deploy
7. clear cache again
8. Every thing will be fine

Comment: There is no such command as `php bin/magento flush`. Also, there is no need to flush cache twice. Finally, switching to production mode will execute these steps, so you could've just said that (like the accepted answer).